# How to make the map focus on one area?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am writing an app about Map. I need to add a button that the map go back to the original location after the user click that button. How to make the map focus on one area when the user pressed that button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GoogleMap map;
LatLng yourLocation = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
float zoomLevel;

map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(yourLocation, zoomLevel));
```